# How to create a user in Django with extra fields

Tags: django, django-users

I want to know how do I create users in Django. I can use [User.objects.create_user()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#creating-users) but I can only store username, email, password, first name, last name. I see that [django.contrib.auth.forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/) is depreciated so I cannot UserCreationForm.

What if I want to store more fields. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Are you using Django 1.8?

Comment: @SunderamDubey No. It is 4.1

Answer (score 0):

You should make a custom user model and manager.
Check this [tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/); it will explain all that you need.